# Codeigniter XSS protection

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss

I've been looking into codeigniter for past few days. It looks promising, but there are few issues. The global XSS protection is not secure at all, it sucks! I've been playing around with it, and I for sure can make so many "bad requests"

What do the codeigniter users do? just leave it off, and create their own XSS protection? is there any existing classes for codeigniter (or php) that help to prevent XSS attacks?

It also seems like the XSS protection is stripping too much some times, when it "works" and the code finds a match.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Just curious.  What are you doing that you are getting by the XSS protection?

Comment: Instead of just ranting, can you share any example of failed protection? You should submit them to EllisLab also, you'll be doing a great service for us CI users..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, CI's XSS is pretty good -- I have run into situations where it does remove something which I have wanted which can be a pain to debug if you're not expecting it.  I've never been able to "easily" circumvent it nor have I read about any exploits (and the CI community is fairly large).

If you are very concerned, you can turn off CI's XSS protection and use a "more" comprehensive filter such as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) -- you might also want to read [OWASP's XSS cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), because cleaning input is only a small part of XSS protection.

Answer (score 2):

I dont turn on Global XSS. Once it is turned on globally it is impossible to turn off for single use instances like using a Tiny MCE editor for content. I have literally gone through CI code and found that is rewrites the $_POST,$_GET data, if XSS is on globally then the data get writen to $_POST stripped.

Solution
XSS Global = off

```
$this->input->post('varname',true); //for clean data
$this->input->post('varname',false); //for something you want to clean manually
$varname=filter_var($_POST['varname']); //raw and old school
```

Comment: FYI, code igniter is great, for an old schooler like me it blends a great mix of programming in the raw with the ease of not havent to do everything. Active Database and MVC is addictive. Zend overloaded, DooPHP under developed, CI right in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `htmlspecialchars($input)` to prevent xss injection from user inputs and kiddo.

Answer (score 0):

I have overwritten the post function in RestController like this to XSS cleaning and saving the XSS senders attempts to hack in attack table:

```
public function post($key = NULL, $default_value="" , $xss_clean = TRUE)
{
    if ($key === NULL)
    {
        return $this->_post_args;
    }
    $val =  $this->input->get_post($key, $xss_clean);
    if(!is_array($val))
        $val =  $this->checkvar($val,'string','','')[1];
    if($val == NULL || $val == "" || !isset($val))
        return $default_value;
    else
        return $val;
}

function checkvar($var,$varmode,$varfilter,$defultvar)
{
    if($var==null||$var==''){
        return [1,$defultvar];
    }else{
        $ttvar=$var;

        $var =strtolower($var);
        $tvar=$var;

        $var= preg_replace('~<script~', '<!--',$var);
        $var= preg_replace('~</script>~', '-->',$var);
        $var= preg_replace('~delete *from~', '',$var);
        $var= preg_replace('~drop *table~', '',$var);
        $var= preg_replace('~insert *into~', '',$var);
        $var= preg_replace('~or *1 *= *1~', '',$var);
        $var= preg_replace('~select *from~', '',$var);

        if($var!=$tvar){
            $query="INSERT INTO attack_tb( attack_ip, attack_text, attack_timestamp) VALUES
                        ( '".get_client_ip()."', '".$ttvar."', now() )";
            $CI = get_instance();
            $CI->load->model('B_db');
            $result=$CI->B_db->run_query($query);
        }else{
            $var=$ttvar;
        }
        $var=filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        if($varmode=='string')
        {
            if($varfilter==''){
                return [1,$var];
            }else if($varfilter=='email'){
                if(filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                {   return [1,$var];}else{  return [0,$var];}
            }else if($varfilter=='ip'){
                if(filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                {return [1,$var];}else{ return [0,$var];}
            }
        }else if($varmode=='int'){
            if(is_numeric ($var)){
                return [1,$var];
            }else{
                return [0,$var];
            }
        }
    }
}
```